# kNN improvement on Spam Classification

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, classification, spam, knn

Currently I'm trying to classify spam emails with kNN classification. Dataset is represented in the bag-of-words notation and it contains approx. 10000 observations with approx. 900 features. Matlab is the tool I use to process the data.

Within the last days I played with several machine learning approaches: SVM, Bayes and kNN. In my point of view, kNN's performance beats SVM and Bayes when it comes to minimize the false positive rate. Checking with 10-fold Cross-Validation I obtain a false positive rate of 0.0025 using k=9 and Manhattan-Distance. Hamming distance performs in the same region.

To further improve my FPR I tried to preprocess my data with PCA, but that blow away my FPR as a value of 0.08 is not acceptable.

Do you have any idea how to tune the dataset to get a better FPR?

PS: Yes, this is a task I have to do in order to pass a machine learning course.

Comment: As it is not a programming question, you should ask it her: http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What kind of Bayes did you use. Just a basic Naïve Bayes Classifier?

Comment: Yes, I did use a Naïve Bayes Classifier. That's the one we used in class. Would you suggest another Bayesian approach?

Answer (score 0):

Something to try: double count the non-spam samples in your training data. Say, 500 of the 1000 samples were non-spam. After double counting the non-spam ones you will have a training set of 1500 samples. This might give the false positive test samples more positive nearest neighbours. Note that overall performance might suffer.